# Can sharing rules be based on opportunity roles

Tags: opportunity, sharing, apex-managed-sharing, opportunitycontactrole

We are looking for a way to create role based sharing based on opportunity roles. We have a use case that if we try to use manual sharing, even with apex triggers to automate the manual aspect, we will exceed the 600 limit. We are wondering if there is a way to use opportunity roles instead. Right now the contacts that need to granted sharing rights or contact lookups on the opportunity detail page. We are wondering if we add those users as opportunity roles if we could then share based on tose opportunity roles

Comment: What's the entire use case? There a dozens of ways to approach this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

We decided to go with Opportunity teams since that alleviates the issue of the 600 manual share limit. It will be a lot of up front manual work, but it seems like the best solution.